# Laravel Eloquent: Looping through nested relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Here are my relationships:

`User hasMany licences`

`Licence belongsTo User`
`Licence hasMany attestations`

`Attestation belongsTo Licence`
`Attestation hasMany vehicles`

`Vehicle belongsTo Attestation`

Example:

users
`id | name`
`1  | John Doe`

licence
`id | user_id | type`
`1  |  1      |  A`
`2  |  1      |  B`

attestations
`id | licence_id | date`
`1  |    1       | 2020-12-05`
`2  |    1       | 2021-02-14`
`3  |    2       | 2021-03-02`

vehicles
`id | attestation_id | type`
`1  |      1         | car`
`2  |      1         | boat`
`3  |      2         | motorcycle`
`4  |      2         | truck`
`5  |      3         | plane`
`6  |      3         | train`

And this is what I have so far:

```
 User::whereHas('licences', function($query) use($search) {
      if (!empty($search['licence_type'])) {
         $query->where('type', $search['licence_type']);
      }

    $query->whereHas('attestations', function($query) use($search) {

        if (isset($search['vehicles'])) {
            foreach ($search['vehicles'] as $vehicle) {
                $query->whereHas('vehicles', function($query) use($search, $vehicle) { 
                    $query->where('type', $vehicle);
                }); 
            }   
        }   
    });
})->get();
```

Now in my filters If I search for 'car' the user is retrieved. But if I search for 'car AND motorcycle' or 'car AND plane' the user is not retrieved.
I want the query to search all the attestations for a given user.
How can I do that ?

Comment: `car AND motorcycle` or `car AND plane` has different attestation_id. You may need `orWhere` instead of where.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
User::whereHas('licences', function($query) use($search) {
  if (!empty($search['licence_type'])) {
     $query->where('type', $search['licence_type']);
  }

  $query->whereHas('attestations', function($query) use($search) {
    if (isset($search['vehicles'])) {
        $query->whereHas('vehicles', function($query) use($search, $vehicle) { 
            $query->whereIn('type', $search['vehicles']);
        }); 
    }   
  });
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks but `whereIN` uses the `OR` operator whereas I need the `AND` operator.